WordPress update bug
I have some WordPress website problems which is mysteriously broken
could you guys help me out?
https://englishonlycafe.com
It was look like this
https://web.archive.org/web/20230203182755/https://englishonlycafe.com/en/

I'm having trouble identifying the problem. Broken is too vague. Can you perhaps supply screenshots and a description of expected behaviour vs current behaviour? The more specific you are, the easier it is to give a definitive answer.

Your website is not really broken. As far as I know, what I see when I look on your source code is some HTML code read as plain text. It means Wordpress is interpreting HTML as if it was just random text.
For example, on your front-office, some HTML is published and readable (We should not see it):
<div class="blog-post col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <div class="sample-contain sample-b"><a href="https://englishonlycafe.com/about/" class="sample-cover">
      <div class="sample-bg bg-1"></div> <div class="sample-borderline"></div>
        <div class="sample-comment">About</div>
          <div class="roll-button" style="display: none;">Click for details</div> </a></div>
        </div>
[…]
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

This probably come from some widgets you're using (but I can't be totally sure, because I dont have an access on your dashboard). I can infer this from this piece of code just before all this : <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget>.
First of all, to avoid losing all your work on this website, you should do a backup (if it's not already done) :

Your database, first, following this tutorial,
Your folders and files, following this tutorial.

So after that, I suggest you to go on your Dashboard, and then on the Widget Area, you should edit or disable some widgets.
This documentation will help you to manage properly this area :
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/block-based-widgets-editor/.
I suppose the widgets responsible for the problem are the text widgets, in which you have probably pasted some HTML : you can learn how to manage them here : https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/manage-wordpress-widgets/#using-text-widgets
You will have to do few tests : disabling widgets should let you know immediately if they are responsible for the problem you're facing.
Hope it helps!

My plugins are Anti-spam: /
All In One WP Security/
aThemes Starter Sites/
Autoptimize /
Better Search Replace /
Classic Widgets /
Contact Form 7 /
Firelight Lightbox /
Integration: Yoast SEO & qTranslate-X /

And Lazy Load /
Media File Manager /
qTranslate-X /
SAKURA RS WP SSL /
Search Regex /
SiteGuard WP Plugin /
SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle /
Smash Balloon Instagram Feed /
Social Media Follow Buttons Bar /
Unique Headers /
WordPress Importer /
Yoast SEO /

I tried to Ensure Proper Usage of the HTML Block in Gutenberg Editor / 2. Disable Automatic Formatting (wpautop)
